# In Apple Developer Memeber center i see Duplicate Certificates with different Expiry dates

Tags: macos, certificate, mac-app-store

In Apple Developer Memeber center i see Duplicate Cetrificates with different Expiry Dates.

My Questions are:

1. Why it is like that?
2. Is it ok to be like that?
3. Can't i delete the Duplicate Certificates?

[image: Screen Shot]